# Как в GIT сделать pull из ветки чужого проекта?

Tags: git, github

У двух человек одинаковый учебный проект. Ветки тоже одинаковые, пусть это будут `master` и `HW09`. Как скопировать файлы его ветки `HW09` в свою `HW09` так, чтобы `master` и другие ветки не были затронуты?

Обычный git clone не подходит; веток других еще много - и их менять нельзя

Comment: Если нужна история, то,скорее всего, никак. Если нужны файлы на текущий момент, то просто скопировать ручками в файловом менеджере.

Comment: нет, история коммитов не нужна. нужно соответствие двух веток, и все...
пытался ручками - перезаписалось все; хорошо хоть пуш сделать не успел